# PHP: upload files to network shared folder

Tags: php, upload, networking, directory, shared

I have a problem uploading file to a network shared folder. I can connect to the folder by using windows authentication in IE. The script is as followed:

```
$target_path =  '\\\\server\\images\\';
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

when i ran it , I got an error message read:

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(\server\images\pic_firefox.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed
>   to open stream: Permission denied in
>   C:\xxxxxxxxx\uploader.php  on line 6

I thought that's because windows authentication doesn't work this way. Is there a way I can upload the file by using username/password? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have permissions to access the folder?

Comment: Are you sure you have write permission to the folder? Try mapping to the drive normally and see if you can drop files in.

Comment: Yes, I have no intentions of answering this question, but rather my own question right now. Are you my twin?

Comment: I'm you from the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running a PHP script from the browser, you are not running it under your user account. You are running under whatever the HTTP server uses as the user name. So even if you have access to the folder, the server may not. The easiest fix is to give the server write permission to that folder.

Comment: @XiZhang: I am also facing same issue. Could you please specify how did you solve this ?

Comment: @Anthony, I am also having the same issue, I have permission to read/write from my admin but still failed to open stream: Invalid argument warning