# PHP and NAS (IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008)

Tags: php, iis, networking, iis-7, samba

how can i access folders like

```
\\10.200.0.3\some_folder
user name: user
password: pass
```

is it possible to map network device then access it using php?
please help me connect to this share and access files there..

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is Server Message Block (SMB) or the open source implementation SAMBA.

To use this in PHP, you could look at [smbwebclient](http://code.google.com/p/smbwebclient/downloads/list).

You might however simply add a drive map to the share on your Windows server, assign it a fixed letter (like Z:) or even simply access `\\hostname\folder` (escape the backslashes) and use the PHP built in directory commands to read and write the files from that drive. It'll be a helluvalot easier.

Comment: yes i already tried mapping netwrok drive assigning it drive letter but its not working, php cant find that drive

Comment: i am afraid smbclient program is for linux?? :S i am trying to do this in windows environment php with iis, windows server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these;

- Make sure the IIS worker process has access to that location (IUSR or IIS_IUSRS)
- Change the website's application settings in IIS to use credentials from a user account who has access to the location

Comment: did you change the Physical Path Credentials Logon Type to Network and try? play around with those two settings in the Advanced Settings for your website. see if anything helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since you will be running PHP using IIS/Apache user make sure server user also has permissions to access network shared folder. Once you are sure IIS user does have permissions to access shared folder, you may try listing contents of shared folder by using path such as: 
`$target_path =  '\\\\server\\images\\';`

Have a look at this questions, might be helpful:
[PHP: upload files to network shared folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299981/php-upload-files-to-network-shared-folder)